Is it ok to repost my question on another SE site?
Recently I've submitted two questions (see 1 and 2) that are directly related to cryptography, but their understanding is based on maths. I'm afraid that my questions don't receive enough attention here, despite being adequate for this forum.
Could I repost those questions on math.se for example? I would wait some time to do that, since only a week have passed since the first question. In addition, should I delete those questions in crypto.se in the case I can repost those in another forum? I am sorry if I sound impertinent but as an user of SE I always try to build up questions that I think that can be responded.
Another question to make in this meta would be: how to attract interest from the users so your question gets responded/commented/viewed? It happened me in other forums, and makes me feel frustrated, feels like I'm going in the wrong direction. Thanks for reading.


Could I repost those questions on math.se for example? I would wait some time to do that, since only a week have passed since the first question. In addition, should I delete those questions in crypto.se in the case I can repost those in another forum?

Cross posting the same question to multiple stackexchange sites is frowned upon. If you do move your question to a new site, please ensure that you delete the one on our site (or, ask a moderator to migrate your question for you).
How to attract interest from the users so your question gets responded/commented/viewed?

It happened me in other forums, and makes me feel frustrated, feels like I'm going in the wrong direction.

The first part is to realize that stackexchange is not a forum. It is a question and answer site.
The difference is that forums are designed for discussion, and stackexchange is not. 
Every user on a forum can post their thoughts on the subject, and it's common to have back-and-forth conversations.
On stackexchange, a "question" that requires everyone to post their thoughts on the subject and have back-and-forth discussion is the antithesis of what the site is for. Think of the topics on crypto.stackexchange as entries in a Handy Cryptography Answer book. Each question should have a concise and objective answer. 
About your questions
Question number 2 is involved. It will require the reader to make a conscious effort to sit down and read and understand the context. Asking too much of the reader will tend to lead to fewer readers.
But a bigger issue is that there is no concrete "question" as such. The bottom line says:

What are other limitations and advantages of using the self power map of distinct generators for solving DLP in $Z^∗_p$.

This is an open-ended discussion type of question - It could require a plethora of authors to write an entire book to discuss the limitations and advantages of X or Y. These kinds of question are not a great fit for our site. A question that can be objectively and definitively answered as opposed to discussed has a much better chance of both remaining open and being answered. 
I don't believe that simply migrating this question to a different stackexchange site will fix these problems.
Question 1
Question 1 is about multivariate cryptography. From what I can tell, there are not very many users that work with this subject. There are a grand total of 2 questions on our site tagged with multivariate-cryptography.
I think that the issue here is simply a lack of expertise. The intersection of users that have the know-how to answer this question with the users that have the time and inclination to do so is possibly an empty set. 
It's possible that users of a math stackexchange will have enough familiarity with multivariate polynomials to be able to answer the question from that perspective. It might require the question to be re-phrased. I don't use the math stackexchange sites, so I don't know for certain.

First, I really appreciate your answer Ella. "[...] A question that can be objectively and definitively answered as opposed to discussed has a much better chance of both remaining open and being answered." Could I just ask on that case "has the self power map been used as a DLP solving mechanism?" But I feel like I cannot summarize the mathematical process needed to reach my conclusions.
I know SE is a Q&A site, I call "sites" of SE "forums" due to a mistake related to my mature language "Spanish" where a forum is a place of discussion or information retrieval given by a community of users.

Sometimes I'm naive and I forget that this is a different model of Q&A site that I'm accustomed. As my 1st question, I think that is more concrete than the 2nd one, but needs the reader to locate himself on the right context. As you say, re-phrasing my question removing cryptographic terms can be easier to read for an audience that is not familiarized with crypto, but I posted here first because I like to obtain first class information/references from the crypto audience. Probably this question can be answered there.

@kub0x has the self power map been used as a DLP solving mechanism? sounds perfect. I would additionally suggest using some markdown to structure your question into different segments and make the specific question stand out using a segment header or boldface or something similar (like how I did in this answer)

Thanks for your kind advice, that would make the lecture more comfortable for the reader. Right now I've a close to vote on that question, probably for the things you warned me in: "These kinds of question are not a great fit for our site. A question that can be objectively and definitively answered as opposed to discussed has a much better chance of both remaining open and being answered." Now I've to figure out how to present the question nicely so it doesn't bother anyone (so remains opened at least).
